# How to merge a select statement with a calculated value as new columns?

Tags: sql-server, sql, select

In my sql server code, I have this select statement

```
select distinct 
    a.HireLastName, 
    a.HireFirstName, 
    a.HireID, 
    a.Position_ID, 
    a.BarNumber, 
    a.Archived, 
    a.DateArchived, 
    b.Position_Name
from NewHire a 
join Position b on a.Position_ID = b.Position_ID
join WorkPeriod c on a.hireID = c.HireID
where a.Archived = 0 and c.InquiryID is not null 
order by a.HireID DESC, a.HireLastName, a.HireFirstName
```

And I want to add a new column to it. However this column is not a column from a table, its just used to store a `float` from a calculation I make from existing columns.

The number I get is calculated like this:
`@acc` is the `a.HireID` from the above select statement.

```
CAST((select COUNT(*) from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = @acc AND (HireResponse = 0 OR HireResponse = 1)) as FLOAT) / 
CAST((select COUNT(*) from Hire_Response WHERE HireID = @acc) as FLOAT)
```

How can I do this? 
Thanks.

Comment: Please don't post on more than one site with the same question.  We can move questions around if needed.  Also, please don't post fairly basic questions like this on DBA.SE.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code that GBN did for you on your [other question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42163/how-to-loop-through-a-select-statement) as a sub-query

```
select distinct 
    a.HireLastName, 
    a.HireFirstName, 
    a.HireID, 
    a.Position_ID, 
    a.BarNumber, 
    a.Archived, 
    a.DateArchived, 
    b.Position_Name, 
    d.percentage
from NewHire a 
    inner join Position b on a.Position_ID = b.Position_ID
    inner join WorkPeriod c on a.hireID = c.HireID
    left join (select NH.HireID, ISNULL(1E0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN HireResponse IN (0,1) THEN HR.HireID END) / NULLIF(COUNT(HR.HireID), 0) , 0) AS percentage
                from NewHire NH LEFT JOIN Hire_Response HR ON NH.HireID = HR.HireID 
                group by  NH.HireID) d 
                    ON a.HireID = d.HireID
where a.Archived = 0 and c.InquiryID is not null 
order by a.HireID DESC, a.HireLastName, a.HireFirstName
```

... this will add the column `percentage` to your current query.  This could probably be improved, but it should give you a god idea of how you can bring the results of your questions together.

Comment: That works, but what is `1E0`?

Comment: It is scientific notation for the number `1`. I suspect @gbn put it there so as to cast the format of the percentage presented to you